# python 3 double loop comprehension clarification

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, for-comprehension

I'm curious about the double for-loop comprehension.

**Comprehension**:

```
multilist = [[row*col for col in range(colNum)] for row in range(rowNum)]
```

**Normal double loop**:

```
 for row in range(rowNum):
    for col in range(colNum):
        multilist[row][col] = row*col
```

Both of the methods yield the same outcome. For instance, I insert 3 as my row and 5 as my col, they would produce

```
 [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]]
```

My question is why the col for-loop is placed as the outer loop in the comprehension instead of the row for-loop? I would welcome any explanation.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In a list comprehension, such as yours, the farthest for loop (`rowNum`) is executed first.

```
multilist = [[row*col for col in range(colNum)] for row in range(rowNum)]
```

Therefore, col for-loop is still the inner loop in the comprehension.